# How to create category and subcategory selection in UITableView in iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, checkbox

I want to create a table view with category and subcategory selection in UITableView with Objective-C for iOS but I do't know what to search and from were to start. The content of the category and subcategory are dynamic it can be one or more then it will be decided by web service result. and all category should be collapse on tap.
It should look like this.
[image]

Any suggestion and help will be appreciated

Edit #1

I have tried something but not working fine here is the code for what i have tried yet.
 [Interest (Category and Subcategory)](https://github.com/varun-naharia/CategoryCheckBox)

Comment: it's not very clear what you're asking... do you know how to use `UITableViewController` (that's the UI component you'll need for this) or do you just want to know about the setup?

Comment: Yes I know about `UITableView` and `UITableViewController` and how to use them and how to create custom table view cell but my problem is how I can create dynamic button and label for sub category in one table view cell.

Answer (score 2):

If you use UITableView and iOS 8, you can use autolayout to determine the cell height and setup constraints inside cell to hide/show the options. see how to implement dynamic cell height – http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift).

I use FXForms to handle such options tables but you need to look little bit deeper into this to be able to subclass the cells properly. Check that out here: https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXForms

Comment: thanks for reply example is good but not exactly what I am looking, Actually I am looking for an example of UITableView with collapse and expend  with checkbox created at runtime programatically not with storyboard

Comment: You can do it exactly the same in code. just add 2 different height constraints and change priority when you want to collapse/expand the cell

Comment: there are 10 example in it an only first few are working others are crashing on tap event

Answer (score 2):

I think you should create a `CategoryViewController` with a 'parentCategory' property.

Initially this property will be empty and it will load all of your base categories. Then when you select a category if it has children you will perform a segue to the same `CategoryViewController` and set this parentCategory property. You will use this property to load up the child categories.